No se me genera la subcoleccion en firebase
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Ionic con Angular 18 que utiliza Firebase Firestore. Estoy intentando insertar una rutina de ejercicios en la colección "rutinas" y luego insertar los ejercicios en una subcolección llamada "ejercicios". La rutina se inserta correctamente, pero los ejercicios no se insertan en la subcolección correspondiente. Aquí está el código que he implementado para insertar los datos, pero no logro que los ejercicios se inserten correctamente:
async insertRutina(rutina: any) {
  const rutinaData = {
    nombre_rutina: rutina.nombre_rutina,
    objetivo: rutina.objetivo,
    calentamiento: rutina.calentamiento,
    estiramientos: rutina.estiramientos,
    frecuencia: rutina.frecuencia,
    descanso: rutina.descanso,
    progresion: rutina.progresion,
    consejos: rutina.consejos,
    id_user: rutina.id_user,  // Si es necesario
  };

  try {
    // Insertar la rutina en la colección 'rutinas'
    const rutinaRef = await addDoc(collection(this.firestore, 'rutinas'), rutinaData);
    console.log('Rutina insertada correctamente');
    
    // Obtener el ID de la rutina insertada
    const rutinaId = rutinaRef.id;

    // Insertar los ejercicios en la subcolección 'ejercicios' de la rutina recién insertada
    const ejerciciosRef = collection(this.firestore, `rutinas/${rutinaId}/ejercicios`);

    for (const ejercicio of rutina.ejercicios) {
      await addDoc(ejerciciosRef, {
        nombre_ejercicio: ejercicio.nombre_ejercicio,
        series: ejercicio.series,
        repeticiones: ejercicio.repeticiones,
        descripcion: ejercicio.descripcion,
        id_rutina: rutinaId,  
      });
    }

    console.log('Ejercicios insertados correctamente');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al insertar rutina y ejercicios:', error);
  }
}

Lo que he intentado:
He creado un servicio en Angular que inserta tanto la rutina como los ejercicios en Firestore. La rutina se inserta correctamente, pero los ejercicios no se insertan en la subcolección "ejercicios". Verifiqué que el ID de la rutina se genera correctamente y se utiliza para construir la ruta de la subcolección de ejercicios. He probado con addDoc y no lanza errores, pero los ejercicios no aparecen en la subcolección.
Detalles adicionales:
Estoy usando Firebase Firestore para almacenar los datos y tengo configuradas las colecciones "rutinas" y "ejercicios". Los ejercicios no se insertan correctamente en la subcolección "ejercicios", aunque la rutina sí se inserta bien. Estoy usando un servicio para obtener los datos de la API de Gemini, procesarlos y luego insertar tanto la rutina como los ejercicios en Firestore.
Posibles soluciones que he intentado:
Asegurarme de que la ruta de la subcolección "ejercicios" esté bien formada utilizando el ID de la rutina. Intentar usar setDoc en lugar de addDoc para los ejercicios, pero no funciona. Reemplazar rutina.ejercicios con un array de objetos simples (sin la clase Ejercicio).
Tecnologías que utilizo:
Ionic 6, Angular 18, Firebase Firestore
async onSubmit() {
    try {
      await this.dbService.insertRutina(this.rutina); 
      console.log('Rutina y ejercicios insertados correctamente');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al insertar rutina y ejercicios:', error);
    }
  }

  async sendData() {
    if (this.prompt && !this.loading) {
      this.loading = true;
      const data = `
      ${this.prompt} siguiendo este formato:
      **Nombre de la Rutina:**
  
      **Objetivo:** 
  
      **Calentamiento:** 
  
      **Ejercicios:**
  
      **1. Nombre del ejercicio (X series de X-X repeticiones)**
  
      * Descripción del ejercicio.
  
      **Estiramientos:** 
  
      **Frecuencia:** 
  
      **Descanso:** 
  
      **Progresión:** 
  
      **Consejos:**
  
      Los detalles del usuario son: joven de 24 años, mesomorfo, 174cm, 65kg, IMC 18.5 y hace ejercicio frecuentemente.
      `;
      try {
        this.prompt = '';
        const geminiResponse = await this.geminiService.generateText(data);
        if (geminiResponse) {
          this.rutina = this.processGeminiResponse(geminiResponse);
          await this.onSubmit();
        } else {
          console.error('No se recibió respuesta de Gemini');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al obtener la rutina de Gemini:', error);
      } finally {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    }
  }  

  processGeminiResponse(response: string): Rutina {
    const rutina: Rutina = new Rutina();
  
    // Nombre de la Rutina
    rutina.nombre_rutina = response.split('**Nombre de la Rutina:**')[1].trim().split('**Objetivo:**')[0].trim();
  
    // Objetivo
    rutina.objetivo = response.split('**Objetivo:**')[1].trim().split('**Calentamiento:**')[0].trim();
  
    // Calentamiento
    rutina.calentamiento = response.split('**Calentamiento:**')[1].trim().split('**Ejercicios:**')[0].trim();
  
    // Ejercicios
    const ejerciciosRegex = /\*\*(\d+)\.\s*([A-Za-z\s]+)\s*\((\d+)\s*series\sde\s(\d+)-(\d+)\srepeticiones\)\*\*\s*-\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\*\*\d+\.|$)/g;
    const ejerciciosMatches = [...response.matchAll(ejerciciosRegex)];
  
    // Mapeo de los ejercicios a instancias de la clase Ejercicio
    rutina.ejercicios = ejerciciosMatches.map(match => {
      const nombre_ejercicio = match[2].trim();
      const series = parseInt(match[3], 10);
      const repeticiones = `${match[4]}-${match[5]}`;
      const descripcion = match[6].trim();
  
      // Crear una nueva instancia de Ejercicio y devolverla
      const ejercicio = new Ejercicio();
      ejercicio.nombre_ejercicio = nombre_ejercicio;
      ejercicio.series = series;
      ejercicio.repeticiones = repeticiones;
      ejercicio.descripcion = descripcion;
  
      return ejercicio;
    });
  
    // Estiramientos
    const estiramientosRegex = /\*Estiramientos:\*\*(.*?)\*\*Frecuencia:\*/s;
    const estiramientosMatch = response.match(estiramientosRegex);
    rutina.estiramientos = estiramientosMatch ? estiramientosMatch[1].trim() : '';
  
    // Frecuencia
    rutina.frecuencia = response.split('**Frecuencia:**')[1].trim().split('**Descanso:**')[0].trim();
  
    // Descanso
    rutina.descanso = response.split('**Descanso:**')[1].trim().split('**Progresión:**')[0];
  
    // Progresión
    rutina.progresion = response.split('**Progresión:**')[1].trim().split('**Consejos:**')[0];
  
    // Consejos
    rutina.consejos = response.split('**Consejos:**')[1].trim();
  
    return rutina;
  }

